# EasyWSDL can't read files (from filesystem )

Tags: java, parsing, wsdl

I'm trying to use EasyWSDL but I can't read any file from the filesystem.

```
WSDLReader reader = WSDLFactory.newInstance().newWSDLReader();
Description desc = reader.read(???????);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDLReader.reader method uses URL.
So if a file has to be parsed this can be used:

```
WSDLReader reader = WSDLFactory.newInstance().newWSDLReader();
Description desc = reader.read(new URI("file:///"+(new File(fileName)).getAbsolutePath()).toURL());
```